# Temporary msg while using usleep function

Tags: php

I want to delay the execution of script and i use the usleep function to make it actually calculating something before output. I want a message to be displayed while it's in delay mode. Example : Once user click submit button a message shows "Please wait we are now processing your request..." and disappear when the usleep times up and the results shows. My code :

```
<div> 
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label> 
<select name="fortune" id="fortune"><?php callcombobox('fortune',$fortune); ?></select>
</label>
<input name="submitbtn" type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbutton" value="Submit" style="width:180px; height:30px;" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<div>
<?php
echo 'Please wait while we are processing your request..'; 
flush();
usleep(5000000);
?>
<p class="textcolor">Your fortune is  ：</p>
<p class="textcolor"><?=nl2br($returnanswer)?></p>//result of fortune
</div>
```

I'm newbie to php and tried the code above it doesn't show the echo msg it only shows together with the result retrieved from database when times up. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Simply: Don't do this with PHP.  Use JavaScript on the client's side to set the timeout. Doing it with PHP is taking up unnecessary server resources.

Comment: Ya i aware of it but prefer to use php instead of javascript, don't want user to see the msg is actually generated by javascript when they view html source code. tq :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has some output buffering, and therefor will not output until the end of the script. You should try adding [ob_end_flush](http://php.net/ob_end_flush) at the begin of the script. Or turn it off in the [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) config output_buffering

```
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
<div> 
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label> 
<select name="fortune" id="fortune"><?php callcombobox('fortune',$fortune); ?></select>
</label>
<input name="submitbtn" type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbutton" value="Submit" style="width:180px; height:30px;" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<div>
<?php
echo 'Please wait while we are processing your request..'; 
flush();
usleep(5000000);
?>
<p class="textcolor">Your fortune is  ：</p>
<p class="textcolor"><?=nl2br($returnanswer)?></p>//result of fortune
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I put ob_end_flush on top of the page and later try to put on top before the form's <div> still doesn't work :(

Comment: then try with **while (@ob_end_flush());**